# Java .jar files and dependencies

Tags: netbeans, jar, java

This is something that's probably already been asked, I have no idea. Kinda new at Java.

I wrote a thing in NetBeans on unix. Everything seems cool on the IDE, so I want to compile what I have (Just two .java classes) into a jar so I can run it in other places. I have some compile-time libraries added (other .jars), but when I build my project on NetBeans and run it from the CLI (java -jar thing.jar), it throws a bunch of exceptions like this.

```
EXCEPTION: Class com.systinet.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler or one of its components not found in root.wasp-impl.SOAP
...
...
EXCEPTION: [url]http://systinet.com/wasp/app/security_services_client:security_services_client[/url] -> I couldn't find deployment 
descriptor (QName="{[url]http://systinet.com/wasp/app/builtin_serialization[/url]}builtin_serialization")of dependant package.
```

Am I missing some sort of dependency when I compile .jars? Should I be placing those libraries in the classpath or throwing some stuff in the command line argument or something?

Comment: If you use an IDE, why do you use CLI to build the JAR?

Comment: Oh, I meant I built it in NetBeans and then tried to run it from CLI. Sorry. Edited for more clarifation.

Answer (score 1):

When you move your project build from IDE to Command Line, you need to make sure all the jar dependencies you set in IDE are now available in classpath. Otherwise you would see issues like ClassNotFoundException, NoClassDefFoundError etc.

Comment: Do I just add the directories to the classpath? or the jars themselves?

Comment: It's upto you. If you have lot of jars then better to put the whole directory in classpath.

Comment: Yeah, but including them still nets the same errors. would stuff that handles SOAP requests be outside of this? Maybe that's it. I'm not sure.